# Add a class to the dragging event in full calendar

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-draggable, fullcalendar-scheduler

How to add a class to the dragging event in full calendar? Is it possible to do it using eventDragStart event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do using `eventDragStart`. In [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGqdkv) I have made a class called `eventRed` and I have set up my `eventDragStart` as the following.

```
eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
    event.className += ' eventRed';
}
```

Dragging an external event will not cause this callback to trigger, it will only trigger whenever the event is dragged from the actual calendar, so drag an event onto the calendar and then when you drag it from there the class will be applied.